# bash check if file exists anywhere

Tags: bash, shell

I have access to a CentOS web server with multiple user accounts on it. These users could have php.ini files anywhere in their own branches of the file system--not just in their home directories. I am trying to find a simple and elegant way (preferably using bash utilities) to test if a php.ini file exists anywhere within a single user's branch of the file system.

The examples below show the only two methods that I am able to devise, but each has their drawbacks that makes them unusable:

```
# Does not work as intended
# Always echoes "Found" because find returns 0 even if it didn't find php.ini
if find . -name php.ini; then echo "Found"; fi

# Does not work if php.ini is in a subdirectory
# This test only works on the current working directory
if [ -e php.ini ]; then echo "Found"; fi
```

Assuming that the current working directory is ~ (/home/user) and the php.ini file is in ~/public_html, the output of each is thus:

```
# First, if the php.ini is named php.ini:
cdsynth@cdsynthetics.com [~]# if find . -name php.ini; then echo "Found"; fi
./public_html/php.ini
Found
# After renaming php.ini to php.ini.bak to test find's exit status:
cdsynth@cdsynthetics.com [~]# if find . -name php.ini; then echo "Found"; fi
Found

# And using the -e file test operator, with php.ini correctly named:
cdsynth@cdsynthetics.com [~]# if [ -e php.ini ]; then echo "Found"; fi
```

Any ideas on how to make this work using primarily bash utilities?

Comment: I recommend finding a bash primer and then write a "find" rule/command/option that fiddles (renames) the file the way you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check whether `find` outputs anything:

```
if [[ $(find . -name php.ini) ]]
then
  echo "Found"
fi
```

With GNU `find`, you can also make it exit immediately when a match is found:

```
if [[ $(find . -name php.ini -print -quit) ]]
then
  echo "Found"
fi
```

Comment: +1. Might consider adding `| head -n 1` to the non-GNU version to try to get a similar effect.

Comment: [edit: I am wrong]

@CharlesDuffy Not sure what you mean by similar effect, as the desired effect is for `find` to stop searching as soon as it comes across a match. The continued search is then no longer relevant. Adding `| head -n 1` is redundant as the piping will wait for `find` regardless. So, there is no "similar effect", just added redundant operations.

Comment: @swalog, the question is how long you're waiting for `find`. Stopping after it finds two matching files (since it's only going to notice that its output pipe is closed when trying to do a second write) is better than waiting for it to traverse the entire tree and emit 30 matching files, since the only question is whether a nonzero number of matches exist.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I tested it, and you are absolutely right. I have a wrong assumption about how unix piping works.

Comment: That's exactly what I assumed. I've just learned something I should have known years ago ;) Weirdly, I've often relied and seen clear evidence of this behavior before. Preconceptions are sticky things.

Comment: I never considered how cleverly `EOF` indicators allows a program receiving the input stream to wait for the stream to finish, should it need to (e.g. `sort`), and otherwise work chunk by chunk, if it can. I'm assuming this is how the magic works.

Comment: @swalog, incidentally, GNU `sort` actually _does_ support working in chunks (and merge-sorting those chunks when complete) -- that's how it can handle input streams larger than physical memory.

Comment: @swalog What you saw was probably either sigpipe-on-write semantics or buffering. For example `find / -false | exit` will wait for `find` to finish, because it wouldn't stop early unless it actually tried writing. Additionally, commands can buffer output so that `find / -name php.ini | head -n 1` may buffer up the first several dozen `php.ini` files and write that successfully, and then not exit until it has filled another buffer that fails to write because `head` has now exited.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I apologize for border-lining chatting here, but I find this quite interesting. Even though `sort` can merge sort sorted chunks well, it would still need to wait for the final `EOF`-chunk to output the result, and as such would also need to retain all entires in memory, no? How can it then handle input streams larger than physical memory, while avoiding thrashing?

Comment: Dudes, you people rock! `if [[ $(find . -name php.ini -print -quit) ]]` was exactly what I needed to make my application work! :D

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ -e "$(find . -name 'php.ini' | head -1)" ] ; then echo "Found"; fi
```

The double quotes are necessary because `[ -e ]` exits with code 0.

Comment: Works, but because `find` (with implied -`print`) by definition only returns _existing_ paths, there is no strict need to use `-e` to check existence _again_ - just `-n` to test for _nonempty_ output will do (or using no operator at all). Also, not using `-e` eliminates a problem with the - admittedly largely hypothetical - corner case where the first matching file has newlines embedded in its name. As an aside: if you used native bash conditionals (`[[ ... ]]`) rather than the POSIX form you use (`[ ... ]`), the need to double-quote the command substitution goes away.